# Верная ли такая схема перехода с http на https?

Tags: http, https

Есть сайт на wordpress, немного допилен и видоизменен в отличии от обычного блога, но суть не в этом.

Надо переехать на https.

1) покупают сертификат на fastvps, они мне его устанавливают

2) затем проверяю сам сайт после установки, как там и что с ссылками. Некоторые ссылки прописывал вручную с http - их много, думаю плагином перевести на https

3) в панеле яндекс вебмастер отмечаю галочкой - https - указываю его главным зеркалом

4) в роботс.тхт пишу - host: https - с таким видом сайт

И да, в чем нюанс. Пока не ставлю редиректы с http на https, так как по рекомендациям Яндекса, пока 
При необходимости настроить редирект с неглавного зеркала на главное. Делать это до того, как сайты будут признаны зеркалами, нежелательно, поскольку в этом случае страницы с редиректами будут исключаться из поиска согласно правилам Яндекса по обработке перенаправлений. На время склейки зеркал, по возможности, лучше оставить сайт доступным для робота по обоим адресам.

Answer (score 1):

Не забудь редирект сделать
Подойдут такие строчки кода в .htaccess-файле:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Ссылки конечно лучше были бы относительные, меньше гемора.
Потом Включи Strict Transport Security и Secure Cookies.
Если где то в поисковиках указывал информацию, меняй её и жди переиндексации.
А всё остальное вроде верно.

Comment: ссылки перевел на относительные с помощью плагина.

Comment: а зачем редирект, если сейчас уже все работает! в панеле Wordpress изменил просто https - и все

Comment: CMS впринципе всё может делать за тебя. Я CMS не пользуюсь, поэтому подсказал, как бы сделал я